# How do I test my FastAPI endpoints with a non-HTTPx based client?

Tags: python, fastapi

Title.

Due to some [library maintainers](https://github.com/minio/minio-py/issues/1276#issuecomment-1520990240) only used urllib3 while testing, any HTTP client like TestClient or HTTPx's AsyncClient breaks down while pinging an endpoint uses that library.

Why? I asked about nearly same thing about this yesterday, HTTPx is always trying to seek or close the file I sent while assembling the response, so in my endpoint, if the file I sent turns into a non-seekable object, HTTPx will not be able to assemble the response.

So I need a different HTTP client.

Some criterias:

- I can ping my async endpoints without messing with asyncio's get_loop/new_loop. Like, I am not the one working on the current code, I don't want to turn it into hacky mess.
- I can send all kinds of data that FastAPI supports.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do asyncio I recommend classic performance test frameworks like:

- https://locust.io/ - using requests and python
- https://k6.io/ - K6 javascript tool written in go and using javascript

We used to use locust for a long time, but while locust manages 1000/req/sec, k6 easily does 6000/req/sec on a single host, but you need some basic javascript knowledge, it also have its own package-system and do not use npm, but it will be fixed.

Locust is all free and have a very good presentation text. K6 have some simple reports I did not like, but we easily made our own presentation using matplotlib and numpy.

You can easily set up authentication and accesstokens and reuse it in tests until it fails (401, 403 return code) and then renew it.